# Perl: How do I extract the inner page anchor from the query string?

Tags: perl, cgi, query-string

Given: `http://www.foo.com/bar.html#baz`

How does one get the `baz`?

---

*I can't find this as an option in CGI::params.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Anchor text is not part of the HTTP request. It's used only on the client side.

If you really want it, you'll need to write some Javascript that grabs the `window.location.hash` property and sends it to your server by some means.

Comment: yeah, that's what I've been using and I suspected it wasn't part of the request - darn.

Answer (score 2):

See the [URI::Split](https://metacpan.org/module/URI%3a%3aSplit) module:

```
use URI::Split qw(uri_split);
my $uri = 'http://www.foo.com/bar.html#baz';
my ($scheme, $auth, $path, $query, $frag) = uri_split($uri);
```

The `$frag` variable will contain 'baz'.

Comment: Ovid, but does your script receive the full URI?

Comment: vol7ron: I have no idea what software or configuration you have, so I can't answer that. You only asked how to get the URL fragment from a URL :)